# is it possible to install old version of gcc compiler, even i already have other version's, on CentOS Linux

Tags: linux, centos, compile, gcc

i installed CentOS6 for some reasons, and want to compile documents written by c++ and fortran. i found i gotta change gcc version due to some errors related by using current gcc-gfortran compiler.
the information of current compiler is gcc-gfortran4.8, and to fix this error, i need to use before version 4.2 of gcc-gfortran. could someone please help my issue thank you.

compiler updates information from (https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/releases/gcc-4.3.0/libgfortran/runtime/memory.c):

- runtime/memory.c (internal_realloc, allocate, allocate_array,
  deallocate): Remove functions.
- gfortran.map (_gfortran_allocate, _gfortran_allocate_array,
  _gfortran_deallocate, _gfortran_internal_realloc): Remove symbols.
- libgfortran.h (error_codes): Add comment.

the error message by using current compiler:

sdfReinit3d.F:(.text+0x388e): undefined reference to `_gfortran_allocate64_array' sdfReinit3d.F:(.text+0x3af6): undefined reference to` *gfortran_deallocate'
sdfReinit3d.F:(.text+0x3b10): undefined reference to `_gfortran_deallocate' /home/ce202025/SDFlib1/sample/../usr/local/sphere/lib/libSDF.a(sdfReinit3d.o): In function` sdf_reinit3d_weno*':
sdfReinit3d.F:(.text+0x3c2e): undefined reference to `_gfortran_allocate64_array' sdfReinit3d.F:(.text+0x3e96): undefined reference to` _gfortran_deallocate'
sdfReinit3d.F:(.text+0x3eb0): undefined reference to `_gfortran_deallocate'

Comment: You can have as many versions of gcc as you want, installed at the same time. CentOS6 : `# yum install compat-gcc-34-g77`..... Other extra gcc for CentOS 6 and 7 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175706/how-to-install-gcc-4-9-2-on-rhel-7-4/47189915#47189915

Comment: noted that i can have various version of compiler, but can i ask how i can switch those. 
like, on the same desktop, if i want to compile A by using new version, but B by old version.

Comment: Examples using extra gcc : `export CC=gcc34 CXX=g++34 FC=g77 && [other command]` ..... ..... `make FC=f77` ..... ..... `./configure CC=gcc34 CXX=g++34 FC=g77`

Comment: is it gonna be same result if i change those (CC, CXX, FC) on makefile code ?

Comment: is it gonna be same result if i change those (CC, CXX, FC) on makefile code ?

my current code on makefile is down below.
CC = cc
CXX = c++
FC = gfortran

Comment: Yes, you can specify compiler versions in a `Makefile`. .... Makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many versions of gcc as you want, installed at the same time.

CentOS6, **f77, g77** : `yum install compat-gcc-34-g77`→ Provides `/usr/bin/{gcc34, f77, g77}`

**gfortran41** : gcc41-c++-4.1.2-1.el6.x86_64.rpm https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ITNcvvDO_7yYAnYw0yVTqtC9k3QCwMcR/view?usp=sharing →  Provides `/usr/bin/{gcc41, g++41, gfortran41}`

**gfortran42** : gcc42-c++-4.2.4-21.1.el6.x86_64.rpm https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yoa9Qvi5XXUv4amfptzNeyeclrpgGxMC/view?usp=sharing → Provides `/usr/bin/{gcc42, g++42, gfortran42}`

Comment: is it going to add command as, ”wget https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yoa9Qvi5XXUv4amfptzNeyeclrpgGxMC/view?usp=sharing”, am i right?? sorry for many question, im really noob to Linux or CentOS.....

Comment: i downloaded gcc41-c++-4.1.2-1.el6.x86_64.rpm, and decompressed. 
should i move this to same place as current gcc??

Comment: CentOS : It's a "package.rpm" → Please install with yum. Example  → `yum localinstall Downloads/gcc41-c++-4.1.2-1.el6.x86_64.rpm` .